# Relationship between sample mean and sample survival probability

Tags: survival, biostatistics

I am not sure if this question is very naive, but I was wondering if there is a relationship between sample mean and sample survival probability. For an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$, 
$$S(t)=1-\exp(-\dfrac{t}{\mu})$$
Now if I generate data from an exponential distribution, can the sample mean $\bar{x}$ be used to find $\hat{S}(t)$ as an estimate of $S(t)$?

How about if I generate lifetimes from exponential distribution with different means (say, for males and females). Can the sample mean be used to find out the sample survival probability as an estimate of population survival probability then too?

Answer (score 3):

The survival function at time $t$ for an exponential distribution with true mean $\mu$ is
$$
S(t) = e^{-t/\mu} \quad , \quad t > 0.
$$
According to
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Parameter_estimation
one over the sample mean is the maximum likelihood estimator of $1/\mu$, so that
$$
\hat S(t) = e^{-t /\hat \mu}
$$
serves as a natural estimator of $S$. A different way would be to drop the parametric assumption and use 1 minus the empirical distribution function instead.

For both approaches, stratification by gender or other factors works as well.